# Get top navigation from a SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, global-navigation

There are 5 navigation nodes on the top link bar.
[image]

I tried to get top navigation from a sharepoint site by using JSOM or CSOM but it returns more than 5 navigation nodes as the following:

- German
  Halan
  Page not found
  Test
  Test3
  Birthday
  Halan
  Test
  Test2
  Test3

In Navigation Settings page, I used: "Structural Navigation" as below:
[image]

I have no idea why it returns more than 5 nodes. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check pages library? The additional pages would be available there

Comment: @MonicaJagani: You are correct. They are in Pages library. How can I know to ignore these pages? I want to get the same things as i see on the top link bar. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the top bar have limited space to show all so it picks latest links only .For test purpose you can try to hide 2 or 3 links from top bar, you will start viewing other links like error page .....

So ideally jsom/csom is returning correct results whereas SharePoint top bar shows links based on available space.

If possible, try to get latest pages using REST api (top 5 , orderby - created desc) to get limited result set

Comment: I just wonder. It shows exactly what we see in Navigation Settings page but from data source (get by REST/ JSOM) then there are more items. It has enough space to display > 5 navigation nodes  and the maximum number of navigation to show is 20.
I also checked all properties of navigation nodes then no different: such as IsVisible, IsDocLib, ...
Thanks for your help!